# Map an array of values to percentages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, function

Why isn't map working on these arrays? How can I turn this array into a percentage?

I am trying to map over and parseInt multiple arrays returned from an API but it is only mapping over the first string in each array and then returning the rest as NaN.

I suspect that the forloop might be messing with the functionality of the map but I am not sure how to fix this.

Also when I check what the data type is on the arrays it comes back as an object.
My goal here is to get the average from the 8 numbers that I am given, in a percentage.

```
const apiInfo = $(".info");

function init() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students",
    method: "GET",
  }).then(function (res) {

    for (let i = 0; i < res.students.length; i++) {
      var curr = res.students[i];

      if (curr.id.includes("")) {

        $(".info");
        let img = $(
          "<img class='pPic float-left m-3' src='" +
            res.students[i].pic +
            "'alt = 'profile pic'>"
        );
        let title = res.students[i].firstName + " " + res.students[i].lastName;
        let email = res.students[i].email;
        let company = res.students[i].company;
        let skill = res.students[i].skill;

        let sGrades = res.students[i].grades

        console.log(typeof(sGrades))

        let x = sGrades.map(parseInt)

        let average = ""

        console.log(sGrades, x);

        let list = $("<div class='infoB'>");
        list.append(img);
        list.append("<h4 class='title'>" + title + "<h4>");
        list.append("<p class='mb-1 stats'> email: " + email + "</p>");
        list.append("<p class='mb-1 stats'> comapny: " + company + "</p>");
        list.append("<p class='mb-1 stats'> skill: " + skill + "</p>");
        list.append("<p class='mb-1 stats'> average: " + average + "</p>");

        $(".info").append(list);
      }
    }
  });
}

init();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="info card scroll shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think there is something happening with how `parseInt` is actually doing the implicit mapping. I just tried in my console and I also got `NaN`. Could you just change it to this: let x `sGrades.map(num => parseInt(num))`

Comment: That worked to turn them all into numbers! Thank you! Now I just have the issue of converting all of them into a percentage! haha

Comment: What do you mean by percentage? average out of 100? if it's you can use `sGrades.reduce((acc, ch)=> acc + parseInt(ch), 0) / sGrades.length`. will give you the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can average the values via:

```js
const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / arr.length;
```

You could call the function above via:

```js
avg(student.grades.map(grade => parseInt(grade, 10)));
```

I also recommend using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for constructing your output HTML.

### Demo

```js
const apiInfo = $('.info');
const avg = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val, 0) / arr.length;

const renderStudentInfo = (student, $target) => {
  const fullName = student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName,
    average = avg(student.grades.map(grade => parseInt(grade, 10)));
  $target.append($(`
    <div class="infoB">
      <img class="pPic float-left m-3"
        src="${student.pic}" alt="profile pic" />
      <h4 class="title">${fullName}</h4>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Email: ${student.email}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Company: ${student.company}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Skill: ${student.skill}</p>
      <p class="mb-1 stats">Average: ${average.toFixed(2)}%</p>
    </div>
  `));
};

const init = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students',
    method: 'GET',
  }).then(({ students }) => {
    students.forEach((student) => {
      if (student.id.includes('')) {
        renderStudentInfo(student, apiInfo);
      }
    });
  });
}

init();
```

```css
.infoB {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.infoB .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.infoB .mb-1.stats {
  color: #444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="info card scroll shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving a proper callback function to the map.
Try changing that line to this

```
let x = sGrades.map((v) => `${parseInt(v)}%`)
```

But this will return an array of strings.